# Unit of googRTT in chrome://webrtc-internals

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

What is the unit of googRTT in chrome://webrtc-internals. Is it ms?
Is googRTT a good value to present delay?

Regards

Comment: It seems to be MS. Generally, from what I have seen, RTCP packets contain round trip data in MS and I am sure that chrome internals is getting this data from the control packets that are being exchanged. Yes, it is a good value to represent delay. It is the round trip of a control packet between the two parties.

Answer (score 3):

The unit of googRTT in webrtc stats is milliseconds (ms).

Reference: From webrtc codebase
https://github.com/xhook/libjingle/blob/master/talk/app/webrtc/statscollector.cc#L141

Comment: hi can you point to any docs which will explain each stats parameters meaning